# POST a txt file to remote HTTP server

Tags: java, http, post

I am a little lost with this problem and need some help with this. What I need to do is make a post request to an HTTP REST Interface using Java. In this request, I need to send the key as the parameter and need to upload the text file to the server. This file will be locally available.

Nothing here is user input. I am not sure how to upload file to that server In the instruction page this is written

This step requires an HTTP Post request to the URI  "someurl.com"

- With HTTP Post variable named key and its value
- and the in.txt file attached

After making this request I will get an out.txt file as a response.

So far over the internet I found this code which is close

```
 dos.writeBytes(message); //here message is String and dos is DataOutputStream
        dos.flush(); 
        dos.close();
```

But here message is the string, I was wondering if there is a way to sent file to the server.

Comment: You need this: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/multipartpost.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to upload file with some key and value parameters

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost("someurl.com");
    //Post variable named key and its value
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.addTextBody("id", id, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    builder.addTextBody("apd", apd, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    //path of file
    String filepath = "C:\Users\Downloads\images\file.txt";     
    // This attaches the file to the POST:
    File f = new File(filepath);
    builder.addBinaryBody(
        "file",
        new FileInputStream(f),
        ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
        f.getName()
    );

    HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
    uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you for your answers but they didn't worked for me. I don't have much experience with API of this sort. In the help section, I found to use curl and was able to successfully get the results. Here is the code I used

```
String[] command = {"curl","-H","key:keyValue","-F","file=@in.txt",
                   "http://example.com/evaluate.php ","-o","output.txt"};
ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command); 
Process p;
p = process.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes in the massage parameter you need to Serialize your file - convert it to bytes, encrypt it. Then send it as a message. Then decrypt and build your file from the bytes on the other side

Comment: server url I am sending the file to is not mine. It is some remote server I am using to perform the calculations I need.